# Problem with python deployment to App Service when WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, deployment

am having problem with python deployment to Azure App Service when using `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1.`
Without this option my app is on and running, without that option I am getting some modules errors when checked in KUDU:
[image: image.png.]
This is my build and deployment pipeline:

```
parameters:
  - name: createArtifacts
    type: boolean
  - name: artifactName
    type: string

jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.9'
        addToPath: true

- script: |
         python -m venv antenv
         source antenv/bin/activate
         python -m pip install --upgrade pip
         pip install setup
         pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      displayName: 'Install Python dependencies' 

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(${{parameters.createArtifacts}}, true))
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        #archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{parameters.artifactName}}.zip"
        replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(${{parameters.createArtifacts}}, true))
      displayName: "Publish artifacts package"
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{parameters.artifactName}}.zip"
        artifactName: ${{parameters.artifactName}}
  
parameters:
  - name: webAppName
    type: string
  - name: artifactName
    type: string

steps:
- checkout: none

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      write-host ${{parameters.webAppName}}

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: "current"
    downloadType: "single"
    artifactName: ${{parameters.artifactName}}
    downloadPath: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"

- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.9'
  displayName: 'Use Python version'  

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(backendServiceArm)
    appName: ${{parameters.webAppName}}
    package: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/${{parameters.artifactName}}/${{parameters.artifactName}}.zip"
    appType: webAppLinux
    #enableCustomDeployment: true
    #startUpCommand: 'gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=4 --timeout 600 app:app'
```

And here is my tf:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "appservice" {
  name                      = "app-${var.project_prefix}-${var.env}-${var.location}-01"
  location                  = var.location
  resource_group_name       = var.resourcegroupname
  service_plan_id           = azurerm_service_plan.asp-python.id

app_settings          = {
      WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1
      ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD = 1
      SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = 1
      AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = ".."
      OPENAI_API_KEY = "..."
      BACKEND_URL = "..."
      FRONTEND_HOST = ".."
      APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING = ".."
      DEFAULT_MAX_CONTEXT_LEN = 1200
      DEFAULT_MAX_TOKENS = 200
      MAX_EMBEDDING_CHUNK_TOKENS = 200
    }
    
site_config {
    always_on           = true
    ftps_state          = "Disabled"
    app_command_line    = "gunicorn --preload --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=4 --timeout 600 app:app"
    application_stack {
      python_version = 3.9
    }
    cors {
      allowed_origins = [...]
    }
  }

tags = {
    environment = var.env
  }
}
```

I am running out of ideas. The case is that when I have WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1 option set to 0 my deployment takes over 20 minutes which is something I try to solve. setting it to 1 is a solution but then my app doesn’t work. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app_command_line` should be `pip install -r requirements.txt && gunicorn --preload --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 --timeout 600 app:app`. This is because Microsoft didn't solve theirs ticket form 2k20:
https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/557
Cheers

Comment: Please be polite

Comment: @Redduke Glad to know that you have found the solution. You can accept the answer. It will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.